# Recommendations needed for optimising bundle size generated by react scripts

Tags: reactjs, webpack

[image: Source Map]
The bundle size generated for my SPA developed using CRA results in ~1.9 MB. Below is the generated source map. I want recommendations how to reduce the size. I am new to build configurations and learning webpack.

Comment: CRA production build is pretty heavily optimized already. Id take a further look on your external imports eg importing entire libraries

Comment: Looks like you are using react-data-grid that brings react-data-grid-addons both weight 470KB!

Consider finding a smaller lib or code split it only to places that really using it.